# Multiple Magento store 1.6 Configuration

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have 2 seperate domains at present, I have installed Magento on

#### www.laptops.com,

**Magento Website Name**- "laptops.co.uk"
**Magento Website Code**- "laptops"

My Second Store Is

#### www.cheaplaptops.co.uk,

**Magento Website Name**- "cheaplaptops.co.uk
**Magento Website Code**- "cheaplaptops"

I have created a Addon Domain for the second store. Copied the htacess and index.php files into the new folder created for the addon domain (public_html/cheaplaptops).

At present I have reverted to the original settings and the htaccess is the original format and nothing has changed. Can someone explain to me what code I should be inputting in both files with the above examples as I have been trying hard for weeks to understand with no luck. I have searched google for answers and I probably have found them but I do not understand what items I should be changing or when I do change them it still redirects to my main store www.laptops.co.uk.

The only thing I have changed on my second domain is changed the index.php file to include the following in this exact format

```
$mageFilename = '../public_html/app/Mage.php';
```

I have amended the code as suggested below but I am getting redirected back to my main store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Magento v1.4 `index.php` contain the following code :

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
```

so, you should modify `VirtualHost` directives as follows :

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "base" # put here your website or store code
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website" # put here 'website' or 'store'
```

so, it should be :

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "cheaplaptops"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "cheaplaptops.co.uk"
```

for `.htaccess`, put the following content :

```
    SetEnvIf Host .*site.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=cheaplaptops
    SetEnvIf Host .*site.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=cheaplaptops.co.uk
    <!-- *site.* mean your site name .*cheaplaptops.* -->
```

Remarks : don't use website name like "cheaplaptops.co.uk", try another name instead of this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer I do not have access to VirtualHost, is there another way to correct this

Comment: without sounding even more stupid, where you have put    .*site.*  
do I put the web address for my main store as below

SetEnvIf Host cheaplaptops MAGE_RUN_CODE=cheaplaptops
SetEnvIf Host cheaplaptops MAGE_RUN_CODE=cheaplaptops

Also do I add the other website "laptops". Finally is this the main htaccess file in the main directory or the addon domain htaccess file.

thanks for all of your help

Comment: put end of the .htaccess also don't forget to change site codes from cheaplaptops.co.uk to cheaplaptops_co_uk

Comment: Hi, i have changed the file as suggested but I am still getting redirected to the main domain, any ideas?

Comment: you need to restart apache server but if I am not mistaken you are working on shared hosting service, its sad...

Comment: @Gumtee right, try to change `cheaplaptops.co.uk` with `website`

Answer (score 1):

Mine is setup as follows:

In .htaccess;

```
SetEnvIf Host .*cheaplaptops.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=cheaplaptops
SetEnvIf Host .*cheaplaptops.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

I also had to create symbolic links to:

app,
downloader,
js,
media,
sitemap (optional),
skin,
and var directories.